Parse data from nested object
This is related to Power Automate flow. Below is the data I retrieved from API, I need to get only ID's (10,76 - highlighted in green) Any idea on this. Thanks in advance.


can you add your request to your api in your post please, i think just add &$select=Approver1/id,Approver2/id,Approver3/id,Approver4/id

Hi @FredericDietrich , I am using '"_api/web/lists/getbytitle('TestWorkflows')/items(1)?$expand=Approver1,Approver2,Approver3,Approver4&$select=Approver1/Id,Approver2/Id,Approver3/Id,Approver4/Id"
}'  , but still i am getting the medata values.

outputs('[--NAME-OF-ACTION--]')?['body/d/Approver1/Id']
outputs('[--NAME-OF-ACTION--]')?['body/d/Approver2/Id']

This is assuming these properties always exist. If you are not sure, you can use ? and split all parameters like this
outputs('[--NAME-OF-ACTION--]')?['body']?['d']?['Approver1']?['Id']

just take that into consideration when using later - value might be null

Hi @Kristaps Vilerts, Thanks for your input, But the above data is dynamic so, I need to loop the data get the ID. Can you help me on this ?

Use action each - pass output from SharePoint action into each action and iterate through items.

Hi  @Kristaps Vilerts, We can't loop the items as it's not a Array. but  I need to loop through the returned data and get the ID's 10,76 (highlighted in screenshot) . Any suggestions on this.

for me it works

To loop on more items remove (3) that filmter on on item id = 3
/_api/web/getlist('/sites/fdiSandBox/Lists/testOnly')/items?$select=Approver1/Id&$expand=Approver1&$filter Id gt 0

Hi @FredericDietrich, I meant, I need to loop through the returned data and get the ID's 10,76 (highlighted in screenshot)

Hi @FredericDietrich, Any suggestions on this.

you want to get all items where id equals 10 or 76?    : /_api/web/getlist('/sites/fdiSandBox/Lists/testOnly')/items?$select=Approver1/Id,Approver2/Id&$expand=Approver1,Approver2&$filter Approver1/Id eq 10 or Approver2/Id eq 76

Hi @FredericDietrich,  I need to get all ID's  that is present in the output response (not just 10 or 76).

ok, remove the filter on the ids, how many elements in your list?

Hi @FredericDietrich
I need is to get the Id's returned from the HTTP output. I am dynamically passing the list name and column names in HTTP request. So HTTP output elements may vary. I just need to grab the ID's.

Hi @FredericDietrich, Let me put it in other way, I need to get the ID's and append it to a string variable from the output array.
